# jquery - lose click() event after ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

At the following webpage [liamharding.com/pgi.php](http://www.liamharding.com/pgi/pgi.php) I have an option panel on the left side of the page which opens and closes upon clicking the panels 'arrow', this works fine until you select a market (for testing use one of the 'Random Walk' markets and click 'Show/Refesh Graphs'), this then makes an ajax call using  `get_graph(forexName, myCount, divIsNew)` function.

Once this call is completed a graph(s) is displayed and then my options panels click() event does not work?

The ajax call returns the data in a variable `ajax_data`, the problem happens when I perform the following code `var jq_ajax_data = $("<div/>").html(ajax_data);` . I need to wrap it in a  so I can extract data from it using jQuery. If this line of code is commented out the click() event works fine ??

Hope somebody can help, I have spent a lot of time but cant find what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe I am looking at the wrong thing, but everything seems to work for me on Chrome Win 7

Comment: yes, u are right, it works here as well on chrome (Win7 x64). I use Firefox (v3.5.9) which has this problem, same problem also appears in IE8 (not formatted for ie8 yet)...

Answer (score 19):

You should NOT use .live as above have recommended, it is now deprecated. You should instead use .on e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(){
    //Your code here
});
```

Comment: Andre, it's inaccurate to down vote and post answers like this when 3 years ago the answer was in fact valid. Please moderate your answers, and votes, accordingly.

Comment: @griegs Didn't see that I will change my vote on your answer, however my answer is fine and is not inaccurate, perhaps no point in commenting your answer, but the fact is people always search and try to use answers from stack. If I didin't post this answer someone who stumbled across this might use live instead of on.

Answer (score 6):

Its hard to tell exactly what is causing the click event to be lost without seeing the full code, but you can try setting the click as a live event like this:

```
$("#clickableItem").live("click", function() { 
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: to view the full code go to the above link 'liamharding.com/pgi.php' & view source, its all there. I tried adding the above .live for the click event but still no luck in Firefox & IE8. Chrome works great ???

Answer (score 5):

You are replacing the contents of a div with new html.  the new html will not have any click events assigned to it.

Use  the [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) command to always have your elements have click events assigned to them.

Comment: Andre, look at the date of the post.  It wasn't deprecated 3 years ago!

Comment: This old answer *still* helped me spot something that should have been obvious. Thanks!